# Estender o findAll com filtros personalisados

Tags: java, jpa, spring, spring-data

Estou tentando estender o findAll do meu repositório JPA para fazer filtros personalizados.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e encontrei algumas ideias de uso com Predicados e afins porém não identifiquei algo que funcionasse de uma forma pratica.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por algo parecido ou tem alguma ideia de como fazer isto sem que eu precise criar varias formas de pesquisa dentro do meu Repository.

Comment: Você precisa que todos seus repositórios apresentem o comportamento de `findAll` alterado? Um grupo de repositórios apenas? Se sim, você precisa de um `factory bean` customizado para os repositórios. Se for apenas um (ou um grupo pequeno), `property expressions` não resolve seu problema? Além disto, seu problema é no uso de predicados ou na fabricação de beans?

Comment: preciso para alguns repositorios somente, um pouco grandes por sinal para buscas personalizadas. Você tem algum exempo de factory bean ? só para eu ter uma ideia se estamos falando a mesma lingua. @BrunoCésar desde ja agradeço

Comment: Esta [reposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950246/27955142#27955142) é um exemplo de repositório customizado e um factory bean que cria repositórios com ele como implementação. Não entendi exatamente a sua necessidade, o quão "personalizada" e complexa, por que no data jpa tem muitas formas de definir consultas. Se você incluir o que precisa como resultado, talvez fique mais simples de ajudar.

Comment: @BrunoCésar muito bom brother, coloca como resposta para que eu possa marcar como resolvido

Comment: @BrunoCésar O que preciso seria algo do tipo, utilizar filtros para varios campos utilizando o findall como base entendeu

Comment: Otto, não entendi este último comentário. Você precisa de algo além da resposta que foi linkada (e incluída a baixo) ou é apenas isto?

Comment: @BrunoCésar vou fazer os testes para ver se atende e estarei avisando na sequencia ... desde ja agredeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas de modificar o comportamento padrão de um método um repositórios com o Spring Data JPA é criando uma outra implementação base para repositório. Na documentação é mostrado como [adiciona comportamente customizado](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) ao repositório.

Os passos a serem seguidos são mais ou menos estes:

1. criar uma interface customizada para os seus repositórios, podendo extender o de [`JpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) mesmo, algo assim:

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomGenericRepository<E extends CustomAbstractEntity, PK extends Serializable> extends
        JpaRepository<E, PK>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> { }
```

Iremos extender também [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html), por que nosso repositório customizado irá usar *specifications* e ela dá suporte a isto.

2. o segundo passo é implementarmos esta interface que acabamos de definir. Abaixo um exemplo que altera o comportamento de `findAll`, usando uma [`Specification`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) que irá considerar na consulta apenas os registros não excluídos logicamente, algo assim:

```java
public class CustomGenericRepositoryImpl<E extends CustomAbstractEntity, PK extends Serializable> extends
        SimpleJpaRepository<E, PK> implements CustomGenericRepository<E, PK> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomGenericRepositoryImpl(final Class<T> domainClass, final EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> findAll() {
        return super.findAll(this.isRemoved());
    }

    private Specification<E> isRemoved() {
        return new Specification<E>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<E> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return cb.isFalse(root.<Boolean> get("deleted"));
            }

        };

    }

}
```

3. como temos uma implementação diferente que usaremos em nossos repositórios, precisamos criar uma forma de instruir ao *container* spring como ele irá criar as instâncias para os repositórios. Então, criaremos um *factory bean* também customizado e que também extende de um que é `JPA`, o [`JpaRepositoryFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.html):

```java
public class CustomGenericRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends JpaRepository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends
        JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new RepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }

    private static class RepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        public RepositoryFactory(final EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(final RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return new CustomGenericRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainClass(), em);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(final RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return CustomGenericRepositoryImpl.class;
        }

    }

}
```

4. por fim, precisamos falar para o spring data qual é a `factory-class` que irar criar nossos repositórios. Usando XML você pode usar assim:

```xml
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.brunocesar.custom.repository,com.brunocesar.custom.repository.support"
    factory-class="com.brunocesar.custom.repository.support.factory.CustomGenericRepositoryFactoryBean"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagerCustom" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryCustom" />
```

Usando Java, considerando uma classe só para a configuração dos repositórios, basta configurar o atributo `factoryClass` de [`@EnableJpaRepositories`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html), algo assim:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(factoryClass = "com.brunocesar.custom.repository.support.factory.CustomGenericRepositoryFactoryBean")
public class JPARepositoryConfig {

    // o resto da configuração continua a mesma =)

}
```

Para usar, basta que o seu repositório extenda a interface customizada que criamos, `CustomGenericRepository`, algo assim:

```
@Repository
public interface PessoaRepository extends CustomGenericRepository<Pessoa, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementa o JPARepository que voce pode personalizar suas consultas de acordo com os atributos do seu objeto exemplo abaixo :

```
public interface Empregado extends JpaRepository<Empregado , Integer> {
   //Atributo Endereco dentro de Empregado ele já implementa pra vc tudo!
   List<Empregado> findByEndereco(Endereco endereco );
}
```